# IntelliJ IDEA: How to navigate to class and line from external app

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, navigation

Is there any way how to navigate to a specific class and line from external app? I have external log app (LogExpert) and I would like to jump to a line by clicking on the log line. So I need to create some adapter app that will process line content from log app and somehow connect to IDEA, that will navigate to class and line.

I remember that Eclipse has some plugin that can listen on some port and navigate. Is there any similar plugin? I didn't found anything.

Comment: On MacOS X, just using the command line `idea --line 3 ~/Test.java` jumps to line 3 of Test.java in a currently open instance or opens a new instance if none is already open. Not sure if that's what you're looking for though.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: For others, it is described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-intellij-idea-features-from-command-line.html#d799993e160

Comment: Btw. you can post it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command line `idea --line 3 ~/Test.java` jumps to line 3 of Test.java in a currently open instance or opens a new instance if none is already open.